# How do I change the value of a modifier from a separate view?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In this code I am using a button in Home() labelled "see profile" to change the selected tab in my custom tab bar to Profile().

This works (changes current tab to Profile() but the  .clipShape(BottomCurve(currentXValue: currentXValue)) effect does not take place. How can I make sure this is responsive (just as the currentTab variable is)?

Here is the code:

```
class AppViewModel: ObservableObject {
       
    @Published var currentTab: Tab = .Home

}


struct MainPage: View {
    @StateObject var appModel: AppViewModel = .init()
    @Namespace var animation

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            TabView(selection: $appModel.currentTab) {
                Profile()
                    .tag(Tab.Profile)
                    .setUpTab()

                Home(appModel: appModel)
                    .tag(Tab.Home)
                    .setUpTab()

                Statistics()
                    .tag(Tab.Statistics)
                    .setUpTab()

            }
            .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
                CustomTabBar(currentTab: $appModel.currentTab, animation: animation)
            }
        }
    }
}



struct Home: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var appModel: AppViewModel
    
    init(appModel: AppViewModel) {
            self.appModel = appModel
        }
        
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
    
            Button(action: {
                appModel.currentTab = .Profile
            }) {
                HStack {
                    Text("See profile")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Profile: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            Text("Profile view")
            
        }
    }
}

struct Statistics: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            Text("Statistics view")
            
        }
    }
}


struct CustomTabBar: View {
    @Binding var currentTab: Tab
    var animation: Namespace.ID
    // Current Tab XValue...
    @State var currentXValue: CGFloat = 0
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0){
            ForEach(Tab.allCases,id: \.rawValue){tab in
                TabButton(tab: tab)
                    .overlay {
                        Text(tab.rawValue)
                            .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .semibold))
                            .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                            .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
                            .offset(y: currentTab == tab ? 15 : 100)
                    }
            }
        }
        .padding(.top)
        // Preview wont show safeArea...
        .padding(.bottom,getSafeArea().bottom == 0 ? 15 : 10)
        .background{

            Color(.gray)
                .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.08), radius: 5, x: 0, y: -5)
                .clipShape(BottomCurve(currentXValue: currentXValue))
                .ignoresSafeArea(.container, edges: .bottom)
        }
    }
    // TabButton...
    @ViewBuilder
    func TabButton(tab: Tab)->some View{
        // Since we need XAxis Value for Curve...
        GeometryReader{proxy in
            Button {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut){
                    currentTab = tab
                    // updating Value...
                    currentXValue = proxy.frame(in: .global).midX
                }
                
            } label: {
                // Moving Button up for current Tab...
//                Image(tab.rawValue)
                Image(systemName: "person.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .renderingMode(.template)
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .foregroundColor(currentTab == tab ? .white : .blue.opacity(0.8))
                    .padding(currentTab == tab ? 15 : 0)
                    .background(
                        ZStack{
                            if currentTab == tab{
                                Circle()
                                    .fill(.green)
                                    .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.1), radius: 8, x: 5, y: 5)
                                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "TAB", in: animation)
                            }
                        }
                    )
                    .contentShape(Rectangle())
                    .offset(y: currentTab == tab ? -50 : 0)
            }
            // Setting intial Curve Position...
            .onAppear {
                
                if tab == Tab.allCases.first && currentXValue == 0{
                    
                    currentXValue = proxy.frame(in: .global).midX
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(height: 30)
    }
}

enum Tab: String,CaseIterable{
    case Profile = "Profile"
    case Home = "Home"
    case Statistics = "Statistics"
}


extension View{
    func getSafeArea()->UIEdgeInsets{
        guard let screen = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene else{
            return .zero
        }
        
        guard let safeArea = screen.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets else{
            return .zero
        }
        
        return safeArea
    }
}


extension View{
    @ViewBuilder
    func setUpTab()->some View{
        self
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background{
                Color("StriderBG")
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
            }
    }
}

// Tab Bar Curve...
struct BottomCurve: Shape {

    var currentXValue: CGFloat
    
    // Animating Path...
    // it wont work on previews....
    var animatableData: CGFloat{
        get{currentXValue}
        set{currentXValue = newValue}
    }
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        
        return Path{path in
            
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: 0))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: rect.height))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.height))
            
            // mid will be current XValue..
            let mid = currentXValue
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: mid - 50, y: 0))
            
            let to1 = CGPoint(x: mid, y: 35)
            let control1 = CGPoint(x: mid - 25, y: 0)
            let control2 = CGPoint(x: mid - 25, y: 35)
            
            path.addCurve(to: to1, control1: control1, control2: control2)
            
            let to2 = CGPoint(x: mid + 50, y: 0)
            let control3 = CGPoint(x: mid + 25, y: 35)
            let control4 = CGPoint(x: mid + 25, y: 0)
            
            path.addCurve(to: to2, control1: control3, control2: control4)
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see when you run this code, when the button in Home() is tapped, Profile() is shown but the BottomCurve effect does not respond.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a bit tough to debug as the example you provided does not run. It appears to be missing a lot of code - most notably the shape you want us to debug. Would you be able to provide a [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @nickreps apologies for that, I edited the question and have provided a full working example of the bug in action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below has modifications to fix both curve start position and curve animations. There were animation issues both on first launch and when tapping the "See profile" button.

Let me know if I missed anything:

```
import SwiftUI

class AppViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var currentTab: Tab = .Home
    @Published var currentIndex: Int = 1
}
struct MainPage: View {
    @StateObject var appModel: AppViewModel = .init()
    @Namespace var animation

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            TabView(selection: $appModel.currentTab) { // Updated line
                Profile()
                    .tag(Tab.Profile)
                    .setUpTab()

                Home(appModel: appModel)
                    .tag(Tab.Home)
                    .setUpTab()

                Statistics()
                    .tag(Tab.Statistics)
                    .setUpTab()
            }
            .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
                CustomTabBar(currentTab: $appModel.currentTab, animation: animation)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Home: View {
    @ObservedObject var appModel: AppViewModel
    @Namespace var animation

    init(appModel: AppViewModel) {
        self.appModel = appModel
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut) { // Add animation
                    appModel.currentTab = .Profile
                    appModel.currentIndex = 0
                }
            }) {
                HStack {
                    Text("See profile")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "Button", in: animation)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Profile: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Profile view")
        }
    }
}

struct Statistics: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Statistics view")
        }
    }
}

struct CustomTabBar: View {
    @Binding var currentTab: Tab
    var animation: Namespace.ID

    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(Tab.allCases, id: \.rawValue) { tab in
                TabButton(tab: tab, currentTab: $currentTab)
                    .overlay {
                        Text(tab.rawValue)
                            .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .semibold))
                            .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                            .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
                            .offset(y: currentTab == tab ? 15 : 100)
                    }
            }
        }
        .padding(.top)
        .padding(.bottom, getSafeArea().bottom == 0 ? 15 : 10)
        .background {
            Color(.gray)
                .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.08), radius: 5, x: 0, y: -5)
                .clipShape(BottomCurve(currentXValue: currentXValue(forTab: currentTab)))
                .ignoresSafeArea(.container, edges: .bottom)
        }
    }

    func currentXValue(forTab tab: Tab) -> CGFloat {
        let index = Tab.allCases.firstIndex(of: tab)!
        let tabWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / CGFloat(Tab.allCases.count)
        return (CGFloat(index) * tabWidth) + (tabWidth / 2)
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    func TabButton(tab: Tab, currentTab: Binding<Tab>) -> some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            Button {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                    currentTab.wrappedValue = tab
                }
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "person.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .renderingMode(.template)
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .foregroundColor(currentTab.wrappedValue == tab ? .white : .blue.opacity(0.8))
                    .padding(currentTab.wrappedValue == tab ? 15 : 0)
                    .background(
                        ZStack {
                            if currentTab.wrappedValue == tab {
                                Circle()
                                    .fill(.green)
                                    .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.1), radius: 8, x: 5, y: 5)
                                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "TAB", in: animation)
                            }
                        }
                    )
                    .contentShape(Rectangle())
                    .offset(y: currentTab.wrappedValue == tab ? -50 : 0)
            }
            .onAppear {
                if tab == Tab.allCases.first && currentXValue(forTab: tab) == 0 {
                    currentXValue(forTab: tab)
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(height: 30)
    }
}

enum Tab: String, CaseIterable {
    case Profile = "Profile"
    case Home = "Home"
    case Statistics = "Statistics"
}

extension View {
    func getSafeArea() -> EdgeInsets {
        guard let screen = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene else {
            return .init()
        }

        guard let safeArea = screen.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets else {
            return .init()
        }

        return EdgeInsets(top: safeArea.top, leading: safeArea.left, bottom: safeArea.bottom, trailing: safeArea.right)
    }
}

extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    func setUpTab() -> some View {
        self
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background {
                Color("StriderBG")
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
            }
    }
}

struct BottomCurve: Shape {
    var currentXValue: CGFloat

    var animatableData: CGFloat {
        get { currentXValue }
        set { currentXValue = newValue }
    }

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        return Path { path in
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: 0))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: rect.height))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.height))

            let mid = currentXValue
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: mid - 50, y: 0))

            let to1 = CGPoint(x: mid, y: 35)
            let control1 = CGPoint(x: mid - 25, y: 0)
            let control2 = CGPoint(x: mid - 25, y: 35)

            path.addCurve(to: to1, control1: control1, control2: control2)

            let to2 = CGPoint(x: mid + 50, y: 0)
            let control3 = CGPoint(x: mid + 25, y: 35)
            let control4 = CGPoint(x: mid + 25, y: 0)

            path.addCurve(to: to2, control1: control3, control2: control4)
        }
    }
}
```